# System.OutOfMemory when I export Excel

Tags: c#, out-of-memory, export-to-excel

I need export a file to excel, but when I use this code to do it, return a error 'Exception.SystemOutOfMemory' in this line: wb.Worksheets.Add(dt, "Relatorio");

```
  using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
        {

            string db = Request.QueryString["DB"].ToString().Replace("-", "_");
            string de = Request.QueryString["DB"].ToString().Replace("-", "_");


            wb.Worksheets.Add(dt, "Relatorio");
            wb.Worksheet(1).Range("A1:O1").Style.Fill.BackgroundColor = XLColor.Gainsboro;
            wb.Worksheet(1).Range("A1:O1").Style.Font.FontColor = XLColor.DimGray;

            Response.Clear();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.Charset = "";
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=InventoryReport___" + db + "___" +
                               de + "___" + DateTime.Now.Day + "_" + DateTime.Now.Month + "_" +
                               DateTime.Now.Year + "_" + DateTime.Now.Hour + "_" + DateTime.Now.Minute + "_" +
                               DateTime.Now.Second + ".xlsx");

            using (MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {

                wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream);
                MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
                Response.Flush();
                Response.End();
            }

        }
```

Comment: Should be closed as "unclear what you're asking" [since asked in the wrong language.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297673/how-do-i-deal-with-non-english-content)

Comment: @mjwills [pt.so] ;)

Comment: I need export a file to excel, but when I use this code to do it, return a error 'Exception.SystemOutOfMemory' in this line: wb.Worksheets.Add(dt, "Relatorio");

Comment: I changed the langague